# Multiple filter (where ...) conditions PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, where-clause

I am trying to run the following query with multiple filters. I keep getting an error. If I run the filter individually, the query runs fine. Do multiple filter(where...)'s just not work?

```
select count(distinct a.user) as total
    ,count(distinct a.user) filter (where d.date >= current_date - '1 day'::interval) as 1_day
    ,count(distinct a.user) filter (where d.date >= current_date - '3 days'::interval) as 3_day
    ,count(distinct a.user) filter (where d.date >= current_date - '1 week'::interval) as 1_week
    ,count(distinct a.user) filter (where d.date >= current_date - '1 month'::interval) as 1_month
    from ppl d
    join
                (select distinct t.user from tbl t
                join date dd
                    on t.date::date between dd.month_start and dd.month_end
                where dd.date = current_date - '14 days'::INTERVAL
                ) as a
    on d.user = a.user
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 2: ....lastedit_date >= current_date - '1 day'::interval) as 1_day
                                                                  ^
```

Comment: I suspect (although I'm too lazy to double check) that your field aliases (1_day, 3_day, ...) can't start with a digit unless they're quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (`a-z`, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (`_`)

This means `1_day` is not a valid identifier and you cannot use it as a column name without double quotes.